# Using flat_map in Tensorflow's Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the dataset API, reading data as follows:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, compression_type="GZIP")
dataset = dataset.map(lambda str: tf.parse_single_example(str, feature_schema))
```

I now want to use `flat_map` in order to filter out some, while duplicating some other samples dynamically at training time (this is the input function leading to my model).

The API for `flat_map` requires to return a `Dataset` object, however I don't know how to create that. Here's a pseudo-code implementation of what I want to achieve:

```
def flat_map_impl(tf_example):
    # Pseudo-code:
    # if tf_example["a"] == 1:
    #     return []
    # else:
    #     return [tf_example, tf_example]

dataset.flat_map(flat_map_impl)
```

How can I implement this in the `flat_map` function?

NOTE: I guess it's possible to implement this via a `py_func`, but I'd prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the most common way to create a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) when returning from a [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) is to use [`Dataset.from_tensors()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors) or [`Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices). In this case, because `tf_example` is a dictionary, it is probably easiest to use a combination of `Dataset.from_tensors()` and [`Dataset.repeat(count)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat), where a [conditional expression](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) computes `count`:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, compression_type="GZIP")
dataset = dataset.map(lambda str: tf.parse_single_example(str, feature_schema))

def flat_map_impl(tf_example):
  count = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf_example["a"], 1)),
                  lambda: tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64),
                  lambda: tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.int64))

  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tf_example).repeat(count)

dataset = dataset.flat_map(flat_map_impl)
```